# Understanding of adapter-pattern

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, design-patterns, polymorphism

I try to realize adapter pattern. In MappingAdapter init Light object, then i return light array.

```
class Light:
    def __init__(self, dim):
        self.dim = dim
        self.grid = [[0 for i in range(dim[0])] for _ in range(dim[1])]
        self.lights = []
        self.obstacles = []

    def set_dim(self, dim):
        self.dim = dim
        self.grid = [[0 for i in range(dim[0])] for _ in range(dim[1])]

    def set_lights(self, lights):
        self.lights = lights
        self.generate_lights()

    def set_obstacles(self, obstacles):
        self.obstacles = obstacles
        self.generate_lights()

    def generate_lights(self):
        return self.grid.copy()
class MappingAdapter(Light):
    def __init__(self, adaptee):
        self.adaptee = adaptee

    def lighten(self, grid):
        self.adaptee.set_dim(self.adaptee.dim)
        self.adaptee.set_lights(self.adaptee.lights)
        return self.adaptee.generate_lights()

class System():
    def __init__(self, light_mapper):

        self.mape = self.grid = [[0 for i in range(30)] for _ in range(20)]
        self.mape[5][7] = 1 # Источники света
        self.mape[5][2] = -1 # Стены
        self.light_mapper = light_mapper

    def get_lightening(self):
        self.lightmap = self.light_mapper.lighten(self.mape)
        return self.lightmap

dim = (10,10)
light = Light(dim)
adapter = MappingAdapter(light)
system = System(adapter)
```

Unfortunately, i'm not understand how Light methods takes variable from System class through the Adapter.

Comment: `system = System(adapter)` doesn't make any sense, because the `System` `__init__` method doesn't take any arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a class `System` that needs a `light_mapper`. The `light_mapper` has at least a method `lighten`. Instead of coding your own `light_mapper`, you want to use an existing class `Light`. But `Light` has no `lighten` method and you feel stuck. Then you decide to wrap the `Light` to adapt it to the `System` requirement. That's the adapter pattern: *the only class you are allowed to (re)write is the `MappingAdapter`*.

In your case, the big difference between the `light_mapper` and the `Light` is that the `light_mapper` seems not to own its `grid`: the grid is passed as a parameter to the `lighten` method. In contrast, `Light` owns its `grid` and does not provide a method to modify it (`set_dim` resets it, but that's all).

It's not clear what you are trying to achieve, but if you find it acceptable to break the encapsulation, you could rewrite the `MappingAdapter`:

```
class MappingAdapter: # do not inherit Light
    def __init__(self, adaptee):
        self.adaptee = adaptee

    def lighten(self, grid):
        # self.adaptee.set_dim(self.adaptee.dim) # resets the grid
        # self.adaptee.set_lights(self.adaptee.lights) # does nothing
        self.adaptee.grid = grid.copy() # will copy System.mape to Light.grid
        return self.adaptee.generate_lights()
```

As this, you get nothing but a copy of a copy of `System.mape` because the `Light.generate_lights` does just give a copy of its grid, but this is the idea. 
Hope it helps.